# TimeSpan.Parse of string including days dd-hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

The time span I want to parse is of the format `dd-hh:mm:ss` 
It is the output by the Linux command that returns how long a process has been running.

Example:

```
string s = "5-15:10:20"; // 5 days 15h 10m 20s
TimeSpan.Parse(s);
```

This generates the error

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
Message="Input string was not in a correct format."
Source="mscorlib"
StackTrace:
   at System.TimeSpan.StringParser.Parse(String s)
   at System.TimeSpan.Parse(String s)
```

Important note: Code to be written in **.net Framework 2.0**
Is there a way to let the `TimeParse` correctly identify the first date part?

Edit: I tried replacing the `-` with `:` but it gives the same error.

Comment: I failed to mention that I also tried replacing the "-" with a ":", but it gives the same error

Comment: `TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(source, @"d\-h\:m\:s", null);` here we *escape* delimiters with `\`

Comment: Have you tried "5.15:10:20"?

Comment: You can looking link = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your string is that the char "-" is a optional minus sign, which indicates a negative TimeSpan. So, you have to use the `Replace()` method before parsing your string.

On [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=net-6.0) you can see all the common chars that works with that method. For that, something like that will work:

```
string s = "5-15:10:20"; // 5 days 15h 10m 20s
TimeSpan.Parse(s.Replace('-', '.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(s.Replace('-', '.'));
```

As does this:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, @"d\-hh\:mm\:ss", null);
```

For more info on the format strings you can use, see [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings).. They're subtly different to DateTime format strings

Comment: Thanks, you are correct! I cannot use the 2nd suggestion because ParseExact isn't available yet in .net Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think that "-" is definitely the wrong sign.
The "-" is for specifying a negative TimeSpan
Since you've tried the ":" shin, give it a try with a "." at this point.

The "." is the official symbol to separate the day from the hours.

Comment: Please, I was happy to help you further.